# Cannot able to save a data while returning that value?

Tags: c#, sql

What i need is to save a data in a table and return that value at last..Here What is happening is it returns that value but it is not getting saved in the table..

Here is the code

```
using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(constr_str)) {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()) {
        cmd.Connection = Conn;
        Conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "Declare @Len int Select @Len =LEN(@CustomerCode) Begin declare @Id varchar(20) select @Id = RequestId from Rode_Provisioning_Process if @Id is null Begin insert into Rode_Provisioning_Process(CustomerCode,RequestType,RequestId,Status,CreatedDate,ModifiedDate) values(@CustomerCode,@RequestType,@CustomerCode+'0001',null,getdate(),getdate()) return End Else declare @max varchar(20) select @max = max(cast(substring(RequestId , @len+1, 4) as int)) from Rode_Provisioning_Process (nolock) select @max = isnull(@max, 0) + 1 select @max = (case when len(@max) = 1 then '000' + @max when len(@max) = 2 then '00' + @max when len(@max) = 3 then '0' + @max else @max end) select @max\tdeclare @number varchar(20) Select @number = (Substring( @CustomerCode, 1, PatIndex( '%[0-9]%', RequestId) - 1 ) + @max) from Rode_Provisioning_Process select @number insert into Rode_Provisioning_Process(CustomerCode,RequestType,RequestId,Status,CreatedDate,ModifiedDate) values(@CustomerCode,@RequestType,@number,null,getdate(),getdate()) end";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CustomerCode;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RequestType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = RequestType;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.CommandText = "Select RequestId from Rode_Provisioning_Process where CustomerCode=@CustomerCode";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CustomerCode;
        string RequestId = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        Conn.Close();
        return RequestId;
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: First of all you need to start using `@` string literal

Comment: Does this code actually run for you?  It should throw an exception on the cmd.ExecuteScalar line due to the re-use of the parameter @CustomerCode...

Comment: @Daniel B:yes it is running..Solution?

Comment: @bala3569 I've quickly tested it, and for me, it is inserting a record, but throwing an exception on the `string RequestId = ` line.

Comment: @Daniel:You have use like this  string RequestId =(string) cmd.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: @bala3569 Yes, I know, the error I get is a `SqlException`, with the following text:  The variable name '@CustomerCode' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things which are wrong, in my opinion:

- The CommandText should be shipped off into a stored procedure, it's difficult to read and understand.
- You are reusing the Command object, which serves very little purpose except to open you up for strange errors.
- RequestID is being stored as a varchar, as opposed to an int.  If you need to keep a numeric value in the DB, always store it as the relevant type, and then convert it to a string when you need it (e.g. `Select RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @RequestID), 4)`).

None of these point to the actual error you describe, but should go a long way towards making your code easier to understand and debug.